# When is Confluent Hypergeometric Function of the Second Kind square integratable?

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, asymptotics, hypergeometric-function

[Confluent Hypergeometric Function of the Second Kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConfluentHypergeometricFunctionoftheSecondKind.html)
has the Maclaurin series of $z^{1-b}$ and asymptotic series of $\frac{1}{z^a}$, so it appeared that if $b>1$ (for $z\ll1$) and $a>0$(for $z\gg1$) will make it converge.

However, whenever I tried to put it to $z=0$, it went up to $\infty$. Yet when I plot the graph, it seemed as if the square root of the integral is converge.

How to deal with this issue, and does Confluent Hypergeometric Function of the Second Kind being square integratable or not?

Comment: A bit fix, $b>\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: There are two leading terms in the expansion of $U(a,b,z)$ around zero. Assume $b \not \in \mathbb Z$ (otherwise we have the logarithmic case), then the terms are $z^{1 - b}$ and $z^0$. If $b > 1$, the leading term in the expansion of $U^2(a,b,z)$ around zero is $z^{2 - 2 b}$, otherwise it's $z^0$. It's certainly not correct that $z^{2 - 2 b}$ is integrable at zero for all $b > 1$ and that $z^{-2 a}$ is integrable at infinity for all $a > 0$.